# extending properties of a class if the other class is already extended in java

Tags: java

I have created a class with some methods which is extended already with UnicastRemoteObjects

```
public class AccountAuthorizationFilter extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Serializable{//methods}
```

I have another class which is extended by another class

```
public class DRMSServerImplementation extends DRMSInterfacePOA{}
```

How to extend the methods of AccountAuthorizationFilter into DRMSServerImplementation ?? Any alternative possibilities excluding the use of objects of that class?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot aggregate the class? i.e. public class DRMSServerImplementation extends DRMSInterfacePOA{ private AccountAuthorizationFilter accountAuthorizationFilter; .... }

Comment: Please expand. Do you want a new class that inherits from both and has both of their methods? Do you want have class A pretend to be class B and show the methods of B to the world, but in fact implement them by using its own methods?

Comment: I am a bit confused but what I mean is that I need to access the methods of the AccountAuthorizationFilter class by the DRMSServerImplementation which is not possible to extend since I already extended it with DRMSInterfacePOA. So, how to access those methods from the AccountAuthorizationFilter class?

Answer (score 0):

AccountAuthorizationFilter and DRMSServerImplementation classes could implement another interface containing the methods you need to use in both classes.

Comment: but the methods which i need to access are already existed in the AccountAuthorizationFilter class.

Comment: Do you mean I should create a new interface which has those methods   to access by the implementing the interface to the DRMSServerImplementation?

Comment: no because it won't work as i have already made it a class which was extended by UnicastRemoteObjects